# Exclude a class from function

Tags: jquery

Basically I'm making a filter for my portfolio so that you can click on "Web Design," for example, and it will fadeOut the divs that aren't marked as such. The problem is I have some title divs houses within "#content" that I don't want to touch.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#filternav a').click(function() {
        $('#filternav .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'view-all') {
            $('#content div.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {

            $('#content div').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {

                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');

                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

I want to add something do that line #content div . each(function) that will exclude things with the class "title." I think it should be as simple as an if statement, but I must be doing something wrong, and I'm very new to jQuery so I'm not sure what this syntax should be.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `.not` like below,

```
$('#content div').not('.title').each(function() {
```

Comment: You are great, this whole damn site is great.

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting because it is exciting also everyday I get to learn something new :)

Answer (score 4):

You can exclude it immediately with the [:not selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$('#content div:not(.title)')
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [.not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

**Replace**

```
$('#content div')
```

**With**

```
$('#content div').not(".title")
```